SCSS - Use of '%' to declare css style
Here's my problem :
I want to do this kind of class in my project (class="h-[2%]"), so I did this little bit of code but something isn't right.
I am not familiar with SCSS so I don't know why 'px' is doing good but '%' is just not ...
/* Pixels */
@for $i from 1 through 100 {
    .w-#{$i}px {
        width: #{$i}px
    }
}

/* Purcent */
@for $i from 1 through 100 {
    .w-#{$i}% {
        width: #{$i}%
    }
}

/* Pixels */
@for $i from 1 through 100 {
    .h-#{$i}px {
        height: #{$i}px
    }
}

/* Purcent */
@for $i from 1 through 100 {
    .h-#{$i}% {
        height: #{$i}%
    }
}

I have tried some weird things like : '%' \% '\%' '\%\' but I don't think it is the way to go.

Unfortunatly i've tryed this and it did not crash but it was showing : (width: 10%;) instead of (width: 10%;). Sorry it did not show it when i published my question. But Thanks !

Why are you escaping it in both places instead of just the class name?

Because when I try to compile the SCSS to CSS an error occurs stating this: fatal error: parse error: failed at height: #{  $i } %;   (stdin) on line 3

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/placeholder-selectors/

I found a way to solve my problem.
Apparently, you cannot assign a value to a variable that includes a unit of measurement (like %, px, em, ...) directly from a variable interpolation. For this I used another method, then the one I was struggling with :


@function calculatePercentage($value) {
    @return $value * 1%;
}

@for $i from 1 through 100 {
    $percentage: calculatePercentage($i);
    .h-#{$i}\% {
        height: $percentage;
    }
}



Thank you all !

In SCSS, when you're dealing with percentages, you need to escape the '%' character using a backslash (%).
/* Pixels */
@for $i from 1 through 100 {
    .w-#{$i}px {
        width: #{$i}px;
    }
}

/* Percentages */
@for $i from 1 through 100 {
    .w-#{$i}\% {
        width: #{$i}%;
    }
}

/* Pixels */
@for $i from 1 through 100 {
    .h-#{$i}px {
        height: #{$i}px;
    }
}

/* Percentages */
@for $i from 1 through 100 {
    .h-#{$i}\% {
        height: #{$i}%;
    }
}

